# OpenLayers circle always appears at origin

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, openlayers

So I have managed to create a circle in OpenLayers on click. However, the circle always appears at the origin of the map, I want it to appear wherever I click. This is my code -

```
 circleStyle = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWidth: 3,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    }

lon = mapApp.get("mapModel").get("mouse").get("longitude")
    lat = mapApp.get("mapModel").get("mouse").get("latitude")
    circleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector "Alpr GeoSearch"
    circle = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
      new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(100,100),
      10000,
      60
      )
    feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle,testPoint,circleStyle)
    circleLayer.addFeatures(feature)
    console.log(circleLayer)
    mapApp.map.openLayersMap.addLayer circleLayer
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here, this line...

```
new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(100,100),
```

Should surely be

```
new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon,lat)
```

Or the other way round (lat,lon), I can never remember. As far as I can see the code you are using is creating at point at coordinates '100,100', and you are never using your lon and lat variables you have grabbed.